# Smart Pointers compatibility with raw pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

I am using a library that uses raw pointers. In my code, I use smart pointers. How do I make them compatible.
For example, I have an object

```
std::unique_ptr<Canvas> m_canvas;
```

But a function call in library is

```
f(..., Canvas* c,...);
```

How do I pass `m_canvas` to `f` ?

Comment: [std::unique_ptr::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get)

Comment: @super I totally agree with you and I am really sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function doesn't take ownership, you might use [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get):

```
f(m_canvas.get());
```

If the function takes ownership, you might use [`release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release):

```
consume(m_canvas.release());
```

Comment: IMO, the decision for the name `release` (also for connections) is not fully unproblematically due to the similarity to `reset()`. We had dozends of subtile bugs because of that in combination with autocomplete of tools like VisualAssist...